# Axios ReadStream randomly closes before it ends

Tags: node.js, axios

I am using `axios` in Node JS to automatically download some video clip files. 
To do so, I simply pipe the `ReadStream` from the axios response into a `WriteStream`.
This is my approach :

```js
const writer = fs.createWriteStream(destination); 

axios({
  url : url
  method : 'GET',
  responseType : 'stream'
})
.then((response) => {

  response.data.pipe(writer);
  const size = Number(response.headers['content-length']);
  let progress = 0;

  writer.on('finish', () => {
    console.log("WRITE STREAM FINISH");
    // DO SOMETHING HERE WITH THE DOWNLOADED FILE
  });

  writer.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

  // READ STREAM
  response.data.on('data', (data) => {
    progress += Buffer.byteLength(data);
    process.stdout.write("\r DOWNLOAD : " + Math.floor((progress / size * 100)) + "%");
  });

  response.data.on('end', () => {
    console.log("READ STREAM END");
  });

  response.data.on('close', () => {
    console.log("READ STREAM CLOSE");
  });

  response.data.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error("READ STREAM ERROR", error);
  });

})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error("AXIOS ERROR", error);
});
```

## Problem

Most of the time it works perfectly, all events are emitted as expected, and the console output would be something like this :

```
DOWNLOAD : 100%
READ STREAM END
READ STREAM CLOSE
WRITE STREAM FINISH
```

But on a very random basis, it happens that the `ReadStream` is closed before it ends, as a result the `finish` event from the `WriteStream` is never emitted. On retrying a couple of seconds later, it works again.

```
DOWNLOAD : 77%
READ STREAM CLOSE
```

I checked the downloaded file after this happend. Looks like the download did not finish ( file size too low). Surprisingly enough, there are no errors raised .

## Questions

- What could cause the `ReadStream` from axios to close before it ends ?
- Could there be a problem at the requested server / file source ?
- Any suggestions how I could troubleshoot this further ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out this was caused by the source file being overwritten on the serverside during download. This stopped the download silently on the client side without any error being raised.

I noticed this while trying a different request library , here : [Reliable file download with got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65231912/reliable-file-download-with-got/66046248#66046248)