# Reliable file download with got

Tags: node.js

I am looking at a few, currently widely used request libraries and how I could use them to automate file downloads + make them reliable enough.

I stumbled over `download` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download)), but since its based on `got` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got)) I thought I would try `got` first directly.

### Problem

One problem I could encounter while downloading a file, is that the source file (on the server) could be overwritten during download. When I try reproduce this behaviour with `got`, `got` just stops the download process without rising any errors.

### What I have so far

The only solution I could come up with, was to use `got.stream` - piping the request into a FileWriter, and compare `total` with `transferred` after the request has ended.

```js
const app = require('express')();
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const got = require('got');
const pipeline = promisify(stream.pipeline);

app.use('/files', require('express').static('files'));
app.listen(8080);

(async () => {

  try {

    let progress = null;

    // Setup Got Request + EventHandlers
    const request = got.stream('http://localhost:8080/files/1gb.test')
    .on('downloadProgress', (p) => { progress = p; })
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log("GOT END");
      console.log(progress && progress.transferred === progress.total ? "COMPLETE" : "NOTCOMPLETE");
    })
    // this does not get fired when source file is overwritten
    .on('error', (e) => {
      console.log("GOT ERROR");
      console.log(e.message);
    });

    // WriteStream + EventHandlers
    const writer = fs.createWriteStream('./downloaded/1gb_downloaded.test')
    .on('finish', () => {
      console.log("WRITER FINISH");
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
      console.log("WRITER ERROR", error.message);
    })
    .on('end', () => {
      console.log("WRITER END");
    })
    .on('close', () => {
      console.log("WRITER CLOSE");
    });

    await pipeline(request, writer);

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.name, e.message);
  }

})();
```

#### Where do the files come from

In the real world the files i am trying to download are coming from a server which I do not have access to, I don't own it. I don't have any information how this server is setup. However I added a simple local express server to the example code above to try things out.

```js
const app = require('express')();
app.use('/files', require('express').static('files'));
app.listen(8080);
```

### Question

Is this solution reliable enough to detect a "none-finished" download ( so for the case the source file gets overwritten during download ) ? Or are there any othere events I could listen to which I missed ?

Comment: Updated used method from `got()` to `got.stream()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no inbuilt way to safely check if a download has been completed `100%` using `got`. I came to the conclusion that my best option for now would be to use the NodeJS Module `http`, which includes, on the [ClientRequest](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) Object, an `aborted` property. When the ReadStream emits an `end` event I can check whether `aborted` is `true` or `false`.

I tested this method in the case when the source file gets overwritten during download, it works !

```js
const http = require('http');
const app = require('express')();
const fs = require('fs');

app.use('/files', require('express').static('files'));
app.listen(8080);

http.get('http://localhost:8080/files/1gb.test', function (response) {

  // WriteStream + EventHandlers
  const writer = fs.createWriteStream('./downloaded/1gb_downloaded.test')
  .on('finish', () => {
    console.log("WRITER FINISH");
  })
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.log("WRITER ERROR", error.message);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log("WRITER END");
  })
  .on('close', () => {
    console.log("WRITER CLOSE");
  });

  // ReadStream + EventHandlers
  response
  .on('error', (e) => {
    console.log("READER ERROR", e.message)
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log("READER END")
    console.log(response.aborted ? "DOWNLOAD NOT COMPLETE" : "DOWNLOAD COMPLETE")
  })
  .on('close', () => {
    console.log("READER CLOSE")
  })

  response.pipe(writer);

});
```

On the upside, this gives me `-1` on dependencies :) , since I don't need `got`.
On the downside, this just assures me, that a running download was not aborted due to the source file being overwritten. When using `http` module I need to include more error handling when for example the file was not found to begin with, which had been more convenient using a request library like `axios` or `got`.

### UPDATE

Realizing that the `ReadableStream` from `http` has something like the `aborted` property made me wonder why none of the request wrapper libraries like `got` does offer something similar. So I tried `axios` again, with :

```js
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/files/1gb.test',
  responseType: 'stream'
}).then( function ( response ) {

});
```

Here the `ReadableStream` comes in `response.data` and it has the same `aborted` property !  .

Answer (score 1):

The got Request stream emits a `error` event whenever something goes wrong.

```js
const request = got('http://localhost:8080/files/1gb.test')
    .on('downloadProgress', (p) => { progress = p; })
    .on('end', (e) => {
      console.log("GOT END");
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
        // Handle error here
    });
```

Various properties in the error object are available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got#gotrequesterror)

`progress.total` will not be available unless the server explicity sets the `Content-Length` (Most servers do, but you might want to have a look out for that)

Comment: Thanks for the info about `Content-Length`, I'll keep that in mind. However, the `error` event won't get fired in case the source file on the server is overwritten. Only the `end` event is fired without information if the download succeeded or not, so I end up having unfinished file.

Comment: that being said (the error event not being fired) i don't know if this is a bug or by design - I just remember seeing this behaviour with other libraries as well, like axios for example.

Comment: @PascalLamers Is it possible to add in your question about the server you are using? Whether it is a custom one or a file server?

Comment: I added it to my question, I do not own the server, however I just added a simple local express server to test it - same result .